# What are the best practices in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, development, best-practice, versioning

Can anyone suggest what are the best practices relevant to the followings.

1. Magento coding standards.
2. Magento naming conventions (including folder names, file names etc.)
3. Folder structure which should follow when creating new module / overriding core files etc
4. Versioning standards.

Comment: These may not be coding standards but here is how I usually do it : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8345/146

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/658/magento-coding-standards for coding standards also :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the followings which will be very useful in best practices in Magento.

1. http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/zend/zend-framework-coding-style-standard/
2. http://scandiweb.com/files/Scandiweb-developmentguidelines.pdf
3. https://packagist.org/packages/magento-ecg/coding-standard
4. https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Magento+Coding+Standards
5. https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard
6. https://github.com/cobhimself/phpcs-magento-rules
7. http://prattski.com/magento-dev-best-practices/
8. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html