# Coding standard clarification in Magento2

Tags: magento2, coding-standards, coding

I have installed `PHP_Codesniffer` extension to find out the Magento 2 coding standard issues.
I have run the below command.
`phpcs --standard=Ecg --extensions=php,xml,phtml --report-full=/path/testing.log /path/`

This extension lists out many errors in the log file from default Magento 2 itself.

So, kindly let me know how to say that the default Magento 2 coding standard has so many issues.

Thanks.!

Comment: here is official magento 2 coding standard follow that http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/658/magento-coding-standards/147969#147969

Answer (score 0):

I think there are still parts of Magento that need re-writing from M1. Also some of the code will be years old so could have been written before they even had M2 coding standards.

With the size of Magento's code base I'll be surprised if it ever fully meets standards.

Comment: Do what I say, not what I do ;)

Comment: Very true @RaphaelatDigitalPianism