# Alternatives or additional tools for Magento 1 EQP Coding Standard?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, coding-standards, tools

As I was working on a new "awesome" M1 extension (after I've read [How to write a custom extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/how-to-write-a-custom-extension/) and others best practice like [this](https://magentotherightway.com/) or [this](http://prattski.com/magento-dev-best-practices/)), I decided to check if I was respecting the coding standards (better late than never).

So, I found [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/658/magento-coding-standards) and tried the [magento-marketplace-eqp](https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp) tool.

It was very usefull and it pushed me to correct some formatting settings of my favorite IDE.

**But**, when I asked about this tool to some other developers, they answered me that they were using it but they advised about a lot of different tools like :

[PHP Mess Detector aka phpmd](https://phpmd.org/) with [this for M1](https://github.com/kubaceg/phpmd-magento)

[Copy/Paste Detector aka phpcd](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcpd)

[PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)

So, I'm now quite lost ... I will try these tools and I will make my own opinion on it.

My question is certainly too much suggestive but if you know/use some other tools and if you think they are usefull (or should even be mandatory for every M1 developers...), please tell me which ones.

In other words, what are you doing to ensure your code respects the coding standards and best practices ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives or additional tools?

> if you know/use some other tools and if you think they are usefull

- `phpcs` + `phpcbf` (https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Fixing-Errors-Automatically)
- xhprofiler (*no support for PHP7 :(*)
- PhpUnit
- [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)

Comment: Thanks @sv3n. My question is more about how to ensure my code will respect standards (M1, PSR1/PSR2 , etc) and good practices.
Magerun can in fact be usefull for this purpose : detect rewrite conflicts and so many others.
Working in TDD is, maybe not enough, considered as being a good practice : so PhpUnit  seems to be a good start for it (I'm trying to use [code-x](https://github.com/code-x/magento-xtest))
If I well understood how works magento-marketplace-eqp, this is actually phpcs (with appropriate rules) and phpcbf.

About xhprofiler, I never used it : so I will give it a try.